# How to set the server timeout in python Klein?

Tags: python, web-services, klein-mvc

I am using python Klein http://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for setting up a web service. I had checked the documentation but I still don't know how to set the timeout of the service. Can anyone who is more familiar with tool shows how to set the timeout to 15 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to timeout? Session, request, ....?

Comment: request timeout I believe? So when the server receive a call and can't response it in a fixed time frame (maybe 10 seconds), it returns time out to the client.

Comment: ok. Can you add ``twisted`` to the tags next time you have a ``klien`` question? This way twisted devs can find your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `Request.loseConnection()` to drop the request connection to the client after an set timeout interval. Here is a quick example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task, defer
from klein import Klein

app = Klein()
request_timeout = 10 # seconds

@app.route('/delayed/<int:n>')
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def timeoutRequest(request, n):
    work = serverTask(n)       # work that might take too long

    drop = reactor.callLater(
        request_timeout,    # drop request connection after n seconds
        dropRequest,        # function to drop request connection
            request,        # pass request obj into dropRequest()
            work)           # pass worker deferred obj to dropRequest()

    try:
        result = yield work     # work has completed, get result
        drop.cancel()           # cancel the task to drop the request connection
    except:
        result = 'Request dropped'

    defer.returnValue(result)

def serverTask(n):
    """
    A simulation of a task that takes n number of seconds to complete.
    """
    d = task.deferLater(reactor, n, lambda: 'delayed for %d seconds' % (n))
    return d

def dropRequest(request, deferred):
    """
    Drop the request connection and cancel any deferreds
    """
    request.loseConnection()
    deferred.cancel()

app.run('localhost', 9000)
```

To try this out, go to `http://localhost:9000/delayed/2` then `http://localhost:9000/delayed/20` to test a scenario when the task doesn't complete in time. Don't forget to cancel all tasks, deferreds, threads, etc related to this request or you could potentially waste lots of memory.

## Code Explanation

**Server Side Task**:  Client goes to `/delayed/<n>` endpoint with a specified delay value. A server side task (`serverTask()`) starts and for the sake of simplicity and to simulate a busy task, `deferLater` was used to return a string after `n` seconds.

**Request Timeout**:  Using `callLater` function, after the `request_timeout` interval, call the `dropRequest` function and pass `request` and all work deferreds that need to be canceled (in this case there's only `work`). When the `request_timeout` has passed then the request connection will be closed (`request.loseConnection()`) and deferreds will be cancelled (`deferred.cancel`).

**Yield Server Task Result**:  In a try/except block, the result will be yielded when the value is available or, if the timeout has passed and connection is dropped, an error will occur and the `Request dropped` message will be returned.

## Alternative

This really doesn't seem like a desirable scenario and should be avoided if possible, but I could see a need for this kind of functionality. Also, though rare, keep in mind that `loseConnection` doesn't always fully close a connection (this is due to TCP implementation not so much Twisted). A better solution would be to cancel a server side task when the client disconnects (which may be a bit easier to catch). This can be done by attaching an `addErrback` to `Request.notifyFinish()`. Here is an example using just Twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/interrupted.html).